# Android deep links are not working with target SDK 33

Tags: java, android, android-studio, kotlin, android-api-levels

We recently migrated my apps target SDK to 33, from that app links are not working fine in emulator but not working in real device

I googled about it and manually opted for web address in my device and links are working fine, but I cant ask app users to do that every time

I have read android documentation

https://developer.android.com/training/app-links/verify-android-applinks#manual-verification

Here they mentioned process of manually verifying the domines for the Android above 12

but when I run **adb shell am compat enable 175408749 com.myapp.package**

terminal is throwing message says

*Cannot override 175408749 for com.modere.global because the app's targetSdk (33) is above the change's targetSdk threshold (30)*

How can I verify the domain please help me

Comment: Read the section named **Invoke the domain verification process** further down on the page you linked to.